# Insertar datos en varias filas desde un archivo de texto php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es leer un archivo .txt y guardar cada una de las filas y columnas en sus respectivos campos en MySQL. El problema es que no se guarda en la BD.
Así tengo el texto en el archivo:

```
NOMBRE,EDAD,SEXO
WALTHER,28,M
MARTHE,26,F
JULIO,28,M
MARIA,25,F
ESTEBAN,24,M
```

y así tengo mi código:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Leer archivo</title>
</head>

<body>

<table>

<?php
    $f = fopen("archivo.txt", "r") or exit("no se puede leer archivo!");
    $arr_to_insert = array();
    while (!feof($f)) { 

       $arrM = explode(',',fgets($f)); 
       echo '<tr><td name="NOMBRE">' . $arrM[0] . '</td><td name="EDAD">' . $arrM[1] . '</td><td name="SEXO">' . $arrM[2] . '</td>  </tr>';

       $arr_to_insert[] = $arrM;
    }

    fclose($f);
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
include 'conexion.php';
foreach($arr_to_insert as $ai){
    $sql="INSERT INTO ninguno (NOMBRE, EDAD, SEXO) VALUES ('{$ai[0]}','{$ai[1]}','{$ai[2]}')";
    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
      }

}
mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar este script.

Implementa consultas preparadas. Son más seguras y eficaces.

Se usa MySQLi al estilo orientado a objetos. Lo digo porque verás que el código varía ligeramente en las llamada a MySQLi.

En tu código veo que intentabas al mismo tiempo crear una tabla con los datos. Eso no lo he hecho, pero se podría hacer si es importante para ti.

Espero te sirva.

Comentarios en el código.

```
$path = 'ruta/y/nombre-archivo/csv.csv';

if(!file_exists($path))
{

    echo "!Archivo no existe!";     

}else{

    //Gestionar aquí conexión a la BD si es de lugar

    $sql="INSERT INTO ninguno (NOMBRE, EDAD, SEXO) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

    $f = fopen($path, "r");

    //Contador para saltar primera línea. Necesario sólo si el csv incluye las cabeceras
    $linea = -1;

    while ($data = fgetcsv($f, 1000, ',', '"')) 
    { 

        $linea++;

        if($linea == 0)
        continue;

        if(current($data)) 
        {
            $nombre = $data[0];
            $edad = $data[1];
            $sexo = $data[2];
            $stmt->bind_param('sis', $nombre, $edad, $sexo);

            //Para fines de depuración
            echo "Insertando: ".$nombre." - ".$edad." - ".$sexo."\n";

            $stmt->execute();
        }

    }

    //Cerrar recursos
    fclose($f);

    $stmt->close();
    $mysqli->close();

}
```

Comment: una pregunta @A.Cadano, para qué es esta linea $path = 'ruta/y/nombre-archivo/csv.csv';

Comment: Eso es para indicar la ruta del archivo. Si el mismo se encuentra en el mismo directorio del script, solamente pones: `$path="archivo.txt";` asumiendo que  tu archivo se llama `archivo.txt`. Si estuviera en otra carpeta: `$path="carpeta/archivo.txt";`

Comment: hola, disculpa una pregunta ese código puede funcionar si tengo este delimitador entre campos en el archivo¨: ¶

Comment: @ArmandoArellano, claro, sólo tienes que cambiar la `,`  por tu delimitador: **`while ($data = fgetcsv($f, 1000, '¶', '"')) //resto del código`**

Comment: si la extensión es txt en lugar de csv. Funciona?

Comment: Sí @ArmandoArellano. Lo único es que debes escribir correctamente el nombre y ruta del archivo en la variable `$path`.

Comment: obtengo el sig. error.haciendolo de ese modo: Notice: fgetcsv(): delimiter must be a single character

Answer (score 1):

Plantearé una solución haciendo uso de [PDO](http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php) , el código está comentado directamente, solo decir que se hace uso de funciones de `PHP` como :

- [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-exists.php) Para comprobar la existencia del archivo.
- [fopen](http://php.net/manual/es/function.fopen.php) Para abrir el archivo en modo lectura *Read(r)*
- [fgets](http://php.net/manual/es/function.fgets.php) Para leer linea de un archivo.
- [explode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) Para dividir una cadena mediante un delimitador *(coma)* , este método retorna un `array`.

  ```
  <?php 
  $rutadefichero = "datos.txt";
  if(!file_exists ($rutadefichero)) echo "El archivo no Existe";
  else{
      $bd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=midatabase',"root", "miclave",array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
      try { 
              /* Creamos La Conexión con PDO, modificar los valores respectivos*/
              $bd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
              /* Creamos la Transacción*/
              $bd->beginTransaction();
              $sentencia = $bd->prepare("INSERT INTO person (nombre,edad,sexo) VALUES (:nombre,:edad,:sexo)");
              $recurso = fopen($rutadefichero, "r"); 
              //Lee La Primer Línea
              $contenidoleido = fgets($recurso); 
              //Lectura linea por línea  , verificando que no sea el final del archivo con feof
              while (!feof($recurso)) { 
                  /* Leemos la Línea */
                  $contenidoleido = fgets($recurso); 
                  /* Explode para separar la línea en un array usando como delimitador la coma */
                  $data = explode(",", $contenidoleido); 
                  $nombre = $data[0];
                  $edad = $data[1];
                  $sexo = $data[2];
                  $sentencia->bindValue(':nombre', $nombre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                  $sentencia->bindValue(':edad', $edad , PDO::PARAM_INT);
                  $sentencia->bindValue(':sexo', $sexo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                  $sentencia->execute();
              } 
               /* Aplicamos los Cambios en La BD */
              $bd->commit();
          }
      catch (Exception $e) {
           /* Cancelamos La Transacción por si exista Error*/
          $bd->rollBack();
          echo "Se Presento Un Error :  " . $e->getMessage();
      }
  }
  ?>
  ```

Comment: hola, disculpa una pregunta ese código puede funcionar si tengo este delimitador entre campos en el archivo¨: ¶

Comment: lo hice y me marca un error asi: Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in, en laasignación de todos los valores del arreglo

Comment: Cuantas filas tiene separadas por dicho delimitador? para el ejemplo solo se trabaja con 3 , indice 0, 1,2 si tiene menos filas seguro dará error.

Comment: son 43 en mi caso

Comment: pero he completado el resto de variables asignando, el valor de cada posición del array.

Comment: Y si hace un `var_dump($data)` después del `explode` ? qué arroja ? ¿las `43` columnas ? Puede que el delimitador no esté funcionando

Comment: solo imprime la primera linea del array

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73411/discussion-between-dev-joel-and-armando-arellano).